Obter listas <li>'s por um determinado atributo com Selenium VBA
estou com dificuldades em algo que parece simples, mas que está me tomando muito tempo. Talves vcs conseguem me ajudar.
Abaixo segue o html:
<div id="events" style="display: block;">
    <ul class="events">
        <li class="evenlis" key="1" ><span class="time b">12</span></li>
        <li class="evenlis" key="0" ><span class="time b">2</span></li>
        <li class="evenlis" key="1" ><span class="time b">20</span></li>
        <li class="evenlis" key="1" ><span class="time b">5</span></li>
        <li class="evenlis" key="0" ><span class="time b">10</span></li>
    </ul>    
</Div>

<div id="tech" style="display: none;">
    <ul class="events">
        <li class="evenlis" key="0" ><span class="time b">15</span></li>
        <li class="evenlis" key="1" ><span class="time b">32</span></li>
        <li class="evenlis" key="1" ><span class="time b">70</span></li>
        <li class="evenlis" key="0" ><span class="time b">4</span></li>
        <li class="evenlis" key="1" ><span class="time b">1</span></li>
    </ul>    
</Div>

Observe que tenho duas listas e preciso pegar os valores de cada <li> que contenha o atributo key="1" da lista que está em <div id="events">
Eu tentei o seguinte com selenium vba:
Dim el As String
Dim valores As WebElements
Set valores = driver.FindElementsByCss(".evenlis[key='1']")

For i = 1 To valores.Count
    el = valores.item(i).FindElementByCss(".time.b").Text
    Debug.print el
Next

Funciona. O problema é que retorna todos os valores com atributo key="1" das duas listas juntas.
Como eu disse anteriormente, preciso dos valores da primeira lista apenas, ou seja, os valores 12, 20 e 5
OBS: A lista é dinâmica, pois todos os dias muda os valores dos atributos key e também a quantidade dos <li>.
Conto com a ajuda de vcs e agradeço desde já.

Use "#events .evenlis[key='1']". Veja mais sobre seletores CSS em https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_selectors/Selector_structure

Olá Syzoth! Eu já tentei isso e não funciona porque após setar a variável "Set valores = ..." ela deixa de ser um array devido o acréscimo do #events

A sugestão do Syzoth funcionará em Set valores = .... Na linha el = ..., você só precisa pegar o texto do elemento, não precisa de outro getElementByCss.

César, tentei sabendo que não iria dar certo e realmente não deu. 'Valores.count' retornou 0. já '"#events > .evenlis[key='1']"' seria o mais apropriado, porem também retona 0

pode informar a sequencia completa de elementos (pai/filhos) para ter certeza que vai sempre pegar o elemento correto, assim "div#events ul li.evenlis[key='1']"

Pessoal consegui relvolver o problema.
O seletor corrigido ficou assim:
"div#events > ul.events  > li.evenlis[key='1']"

Abaixo segue o trecho de codigo completo:
Dim el As String
Dim valores As WebElements

Set valores = driver.FindElementsByCss("div#events > ul.events  > li.evenlis[key='1']")

For i = 1 To valores.Count
    el = valores.item(i).FindElementByCss(".time.b").Text
    Debug.print el
Next

Agradeço a todos pela atenção. Obrigado

No meu caso em específico foi necessário o .FindElementByCss(".time.b"), pois havia mais elementos no código fonte com class="evenlis" key="1" não mencionados aqui que não me interessava, por isso usei para filtrar.
